# Activate camera inside a tab (android)

Tags: android, tabs, camera, orientation

I am trying to develop an application with 3 tabs, so that the 1st tab enables the camera and captures an image. So far I have 2 issues with the camera:

1. I want the camera to lock either in portrait or landscape mode. If I lock the camera in portrait then the image seems rotated and I have tried almost everything with camera.parameters but can't fix it. If I lock the camera in landscape mode then the problem is that the tabs menu also change orientation to landscape. Is there a way to change the orientation only inside that tab and leave the tabs menu in portrait mode?
2. The image is somehow stretched. I guess the problem is that the camera uses height and width of the full screen, but my app tries to fit the camera preview inside a framelayout that is smaller than the screen because of the tabs menu, so that way the image is stretched. Is there any way to fix this and show the actual camera preview with the tabs menu on it?

I use 1 activity that creates the 3 tabs and uses this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I use 1 activity for each tab. Specifically for the 1st tab (camera) I use the preview.class in the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<FrameLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/preview" android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</FrameLayout>
<Button android:text="Click" android:id="@+id/buttonClick" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with 3 tabs where the first tab has to be the camera preview in portrait mode without distortion.
Well that's possible with 3 tricks :)

First set your sub preview activity with portrait mode to force the tab to be in portrait.
Either use in onCreate()

```
this.getParent().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or in manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Then to rotate the screen you should not use parameter since it doesn't work but (only since 2.2)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 ) camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Finally to avoid strectch you can but the FameLayout in fullscreen and make it go under the tabs (tabs is like an overlay but camera underneath is fullscreen without distortion)

```
<TabWidget
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"/>
```

Et voila!